# How to make multiple changes to REQUEST_URI at once?

Tags: apache-2.4, mod-rewrite

I'm dealing with requests from a proprietary client, that *sometimes* uses back- rather than forward-slashes: `GET /path\to\the\file.txt`, and I'd like to straighten them all out.

mod_rewrite can replace one at a time:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)\\+(.*) $1/$2 [QSA]
```

but how would I replace *all* such occurrences at once, like sed's `/g` modifier?

Update, according to the [flag [N] documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_n) kindly linked to by @esa-jokinen, the simple rule below should "just work":

```
RewriteRule "(.*)\\+(.*)" "$1/$2" [N,QSA]
```

but it does not -- the `%{REQUEST_URI}` still has backslashes (not even the first nor last are substituted).

I tried adding the [`noescape` flag](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_ne) too: `[NE,N,QSA]`, but that didn't help...

I know, the matching works, because, if I add R=301 to the flags, I do get a proper redirect sent to the client, with all of the backslashes properly changed. But I don't want to rely on the client's ability to process redirects -- yet, internally, the %{REQUEST_URI} remains unmodified, with all the backslashes intact...

My Apache is of version 2.4.6 -- the latest available from RedHat for RHEL7 we're using..

Comment: Beware of order/interaction with existing rules, especially B/BNP/BCTLS/BNE.. depending on the client you are working with, at least one explicit redirect may be preferable to internal rewrites.

Comment: Considering this vendor's software quality, I doubt, this client can handle redirects _at all_...

Comment: "the `%{REQUEST_URI}` still has backslashes" - How exactly are you testing this?

Comment: After this rule, I also have an `<If>` container, which is checking, whether the `%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI}` exists. With `strace` attached to the `httpd`-process I can see, what path it is verifying (using stat(2)). That path contains unmodified backslashes :-(

Answer (score 1):

Should be possible with something like:

```
RewriteRule ^/([^\\]*)\\([^\\]*\\.*) /$1/$2 [N]
RewriteRule ^/([^\\]*)\\([^\\]*)$ /$1/$2
```

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_n

> The [N] flag causes the ruleset to start over again from the top,
> using the result of the ruleset so far as a starting point. Use with
> extreme caution, as it may result in loop.

Comment: The even simpler example in the [documentation for flag N](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_n) purports to do exactly, what I need -- replace all occurrences of letter "A" with "B". And yet, it does not work for me, when I use `"\\"` instead of "A" and `"/"` instead of "B" -- the `%{REQUEST_URI}` still contains back-slashes afterwards...